# extract quarter from date field and display like Q4:YYYY format in query results

Tags: postgresql

trouble with formatting using `to_char`

```
extract (quarter FROM reviewedon) AS quarter
```

returns `4`

I need it to display as `Q4:YYYY`

Here is my script:

```
extract to_char((quarter FROM reviewedon),'"Q"Q:yyyy') AS quarter
```

this is the error I am getting:

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "("
> LINE 66: extract to_char((quarter FROM reviewedon),'"Q"Q:yyyy') AS qu...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you only need `to_char()`

```
to_char(reviewdon, '"Q"q:yyyy')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the double pipe concatenation as below

```
'Q' || date_part('quarter', reviewdon) || ':' || date_part('year', reviewdon)
```